# Multi-label image classification model only gives high probability prediction to 1 label from an image that contains more than 1 label

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, multilabel-classification

```
from efficientnet_v2 import EfficientNetV2B0
def build_model(num_classes=108):
    base_model = EfficientNetV2B0(
        input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
        include_top=False,
        pooling="avg",
        weights="imagenet-21k-ft1k"
    )

base_model.trainable=False

return tf.keras.Sequential([
    base_model,
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')
])

model = build_model()
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=        
['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
batch_size=32)

img = image.load_img('apple-banana.jpg',target_size=(224,224,3))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
img = img/255

classes = np.array(train.columns[1:])
proba = model.predict(img.reshape(1,224,224,3))
top_3 = np.argsort(proba[0])[:-6:-1]
for i in range(5):
    print("{}".format(classes[top_3[i]])+" ({:.5})".format(proba[0][top_3[I]]))
plt.imshow(img)
```

How do I get my model to distribute a balanced probability prediction?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hWeK.png (Apple prediction)

What I expect to happen is that the probability prediction on the ingredients are balanced. From the image above it predicts the label correctly .Whereas the image below has 2 ingredients in the image, but only 1 ingredient gets a high probability prediction. I think the problem has something to do with object-localization, it might only recognize the banana and ignore the apples.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/22SNN.png (Apple-banana prediction)

How do I fix this?
Is there a way to independently predict each label from 0-1 and apply a threshold of 0.5. For example:

Banana (0.9)

Apple (0.8)

Avocado (0.1)

Plum (0.3)

So unlike my prediction output, the sum of all the predictions does not necessarily need to be equal to 1.

Comment: Please post as text not screenshot.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow ! Can you show us some code for the model you're using? What's its structure, if you trained it yourself what loss did you use?

Comment: Hi, I have attached my code for the model and I used Binary Crossentropy for its loss.